# Can I show the "All Apps" section of the Metro Start screen using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, modern-ui

In Windows 8.1, if I move my mouse to the bottom left of the Start screen, I see a small arrow in a circle.  Clicking it shows all installed applications.  I cannot figure out how to show this without using the mouse.  Is there a key combination I'm missing?

Comment: Related info from MS: [Mouse and keyboard: What's new in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/mouse-keyboard-whats-new), [Getting around your PC - For touch, mouse, and keyboard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/getting-around-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

After you've opened the start screen, you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight the down arrow, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the `All apps` screen. From there, you can use the arrow keys to select an application and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch it. If you want to go back to the main start screen, just use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> again as before.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> can also be used to access account options, power options and the search functionality (all found in the top right of the start screen).

Comment: This does get the job done, though it seems like there should be a simpler way.  <kbd>PgDn</kbd> moves the selection cursor between "groups" in the main Start screen, rather than changing to the All Apps screen as I'd expect, for example.  If there's not a single-key way to do this, I'll accept your answer, but it seems like an oversight.